# How to reorder elements by name and id after removing dynamic element with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have dynamic element and field on the form.

JS :

```
<script>
function hapus(i){
    $("#field"+i).remove();
}
</script>
```

HTML :

```
<div class="fieldwrapper" id="field1">
       <select class="fieldtype" id="labensmittel1" name="data[Tagebuch][labensmitell1]" style="width:160px;">
            <option value="data">data</option>
       </select>
       <input type="text" value="" id="qty1" name="data[Tagebuch][qty1]" class="fieldname" />
       <input type="text" value="" id="labendata1" name="data[Tagebuch][labendata1]" class="fieldname" />
       <input type="button" class="hapus1" value="-" style="width:20px;" id="hapus1" onclick="hapus(1);" />
</div>
<div class="fieldwrapper" id="field2">
       <select class="fieldtype" id="labensmittel2" name="data[Tagebuch][labensmitell2]" style="width:160px;">
            <option value="data">data</option>
       </select>
       <input type="text" value="" id="qty2" name="data[Tagebuch][qty2]" class="fieldname" />
       <input type="text" value="" id="labendata2" name="data[Tagebuch][labendata2]" class="fieldname" />
       <input type="button" class="hapus2" value="-" style="width:20px;" id="hapus2" onclick="hapus(1);" />
</div>
<div class="fieldwrapper" id="field3">
       <select class="fieldtype" id="labensmittel3" name="data[Tagebuch][labensmitell3]" style="width:160px;">
            <option value="data">data</option>
       </select>
       <input type="text" value="" id="qty3" name="data[Tagebuch][qty3]" class="fieldname" />
       <input type="text" value="" id="labendata3" name="data[Tagebuch][labendata3]" class="fieldname" />
       <input type="button" class="hapus3" value="-" style="width:20px;" id="hapus3" onclick="hapus(3);" />
</div>
```

How can I reorder the fields by name? For example if I remove `field2` `div id='field3'` will be changed into `div id='field2'` then the select and input field id and name from `id="labensmittel3"` and `name="data[Tagebuch][labensmitell3]"` will be moved to `id="labensmittel2"` and `name="data[Tagebuch][labensmitell2]"`

Thanks

Comment: Why not just use arrays for everything here (including the jQuery selector)?

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4rWv6/1/

Comment: why do you have the dependency on the id...

Answer (score 6):

How about a basic iteration after the delete happens that resets all of your ids:

```
var fields = $('.fieldwrapper');
var count = 1;
$.each(fields, function() {
    $(this).attr('id','field' + count);
    count++;
});
```

Comment: how about also change input box name like name="data[Tagebuch][qty3]" also change to name="data[Tagebuch][qty2]"

Comment: Same thing. Just change the selector to `$('.fieldwrapper > .fieldname')` and then in the loop: `this.attr('name', 'newValue')`